# What is Never in PassthroughSubject?

Tags: swiftui, combine

For an class in `SwiftUI` to conform to `BindableObject`, it has to have a Publisher, usually `didChange`, which in all of the SwiftUI documentation and videos I've seen so far, is a `PassthroughSubject`.

For example, if you have a class called `TestObject`, `didChange` might equal `PassthroughSubject<TestObject, Never>()`. I understand that the first type is the type of the data that the `PassthroughSubject` passes on, but what is `Never`? What is its purpose and are there any scenarios where the second type is not `Never`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second type provided to `PassthroughSubject` is the type used in case of failure.

```
final class PassthroughSubject<Output, Failure> where Failure : Error
```

The only requirement for this type is to conform to `Error`.

You can use an error type when the way you get your data can produce an error, like a network error for example.

Comment: So instead of having `didChange(self)` would you pass it an error in that case?

Comment: @RPatel99 You actually have to send a "failure" completion with the desired error: `didChange.send(completion: .failure(theError))`

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer does not address what `Never` is and why we may use it with a `PassthroughSubject`.

`Never` is defined as a enum with no cases. This means it can never be constructed. Sounds useless. However it can very useful to make sure functions behave as expected.

For example `fatalError`. `fatalError` will never return because it crashes the application. So you might be tempted to declare it as:

`func fatalError() {}`

However this would not be correct. The above function is actually returning an empty tuple (like all functions declared as above in swift). To be type correct we want to let the compiler know that if this function is called it will never return to the code that originally called it. Therefore we can use `Never`.

**Never in PassthroughSubject**

Sometimes we want `Subjects` that can never send errors. By declaring:

`PassthroughSubject<TestObject, Never>()`

you are saying that this subject will never fail with an error. So in our code we can't call the following because we can't construct a `Never` type to pass into the `.failure`:

`subject.send(completion: .failure(<Nothing to construct here>))`

For example: Let's say we had a timer and we wanted to publish events every 5 seconds. We could use a `PassthroughSubject` to send messages every 5 seconds to its subscribers. However we know it can't fail so to be clear to any consumers of our `api` that they don't need to worry about handling the failure case we can declare the `PassthroughSubject` with `Never` as the `Error` type.

**Note:**

The stream can still be terminated using the following:

`subject.send(completion: .finished)`